# Unable to write to file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm trying to write user input to file in python but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
filename='guest_book.txt'
while True:
    with open(filename,'a') as file_object：
        name=input('Please enter your name')
        file_object.write(name)
        file.object.write('visit the website')
        print('Hello')
```

Comment: please add a bit more context

Comment: What happens (output, full error messages), what should happen/be shown? Edit the question to show it.

Comment: It looks like you tried to retype your code into the question box instead of copy-pasting. In doing so, you introduced discrepancies between your actual code and what you posted. Instead, please copy-paste the code from a file you actually ran.

Comment: ``while True`` ? that will be like infinite/never ending, asking you to enter name. Also ``file.object.write('visit the website')`` should be ``file_object.write('visit the website')``

Answer (score 0):

Some systems dont write to a file until there is a certain amount of data in the buffer to send. Or what sometimes happens is that files aren't written until you close the file.

Anyway this code works on W10 x64 Python 3.7. The file is updated on the fly as you would expect to happen.

```
exit_loop = False
filename='guest_book.txt'

while exit_loop == False:

    with open(filename,'a') as file_object:

        name=input('Please enter your name: ')
        if name == 'xxx':
            exit_loop = True
        else:
            file_object.write(name)
            file_object.write('visit the website')
```

Comment: ``file_object.close()`` ? why ?

Comment: The file is closed in each loop iteration anyway because the `with` block is left.